JWT token creation in android- Without using any 3rd party tool
I tried creating JWT token in android without using any 3rd party library.
Signature is getting  generated, but the generated Signature is invalid.
My Private is below
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

I need to create jwt token with ES384 Algorithm.
Below is my source code
class JWT1 {

    fun generateJWT(privateKeyString: String, header: JSONObject, payload: JSONObject): String {
        // Encode the header and payload to Base64
        val headerBase64 = java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(header.toString().toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        val payloadBase64 = java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(payload.toString().toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))

        // Create the unsigned token
        val unsignedToken = "$headerBase64.$payloadBase64"

        // Sign the token
        val signedToken = signWithPrivateKey(unsignedToken, privateKeyString)

        // Encode the signature in Base64
        val signatureBase64 = java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(signedToken)

        // Return the complete JWT
        return "$unsignedToken.$signatureBase64"
    }

    private fun signWithPrivateKey(unsignedToken: String, privateKeyString: String): ByteArray {
        // Convert the private key string to a PrivateKey object
        val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")

        val keyBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString)
        val keySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
        val privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec) as ECPrivateKey

        // Sign the token
        val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA384withECDSA")
        signature.initSign(privateKey)
        signature.update(unsignedToken.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        return signature.sign()
    }

    fun getToken(): String {
               // private key
               val privatePem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n" +
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n" +
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n" +
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=\n" +
                "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

        val header = JSONObject().apply {
            put("alg", "ES384")
            put("typ", "JWT")
        }
        val privateKeyString = privatePem.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("\n", "")
        return generateJWT(privateKeyString, header, JSONObject(payload))
    }

    private val payload: Map<String, Any>
        get() {
            return mapOf(
                "data" to "hello"
            )
        }
}

I need native android based implementation without using any 3rd party library.
